# How to display an error message from servlet?

Tags: html, jakarta-ee

I want to display an error message when the login and the password are wrong, I tried this attempt but it didnt't work, thanks.

index.html

```
<body>
<form action="Serv">
<input type="text" name="log">
<input type="password" name="pwd">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
</body>
```

Serv.java

```
 response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
 String u =request.getParameter("log");
 String p =request.getParameter("pwd");
 if(u != "admin"  && p!= "admin"){
 String someMessage = "Error !";
 getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.html").forward(request, response); 
 out.println("<html><head>");

out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript");
   out.println("alert("+ someMessage +");</script>");
out.println("</head><body></body></html>");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes inside when it is possible, try this:

```
String someMessage = "Error !";
out.println("<script type='text/javascript'>");
out.println("alert(" + "'" + someMessage + "'" + ");</script>");
out.println("</head><body></body></html>");
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are not closing the quote or script tag, add the closing quote/angle bracket:

```
out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
```